# How to unit test spring PostConstruct and change application properties

Tags: spring, junit, opencsv

I created a small application that in startup load excel file using openCsv in init method. The app loads my excel from the path that I gave in application.properties.

Now I want to do some tests for that. How can I test this scenario? I want to create an excel file in each test but with a different value and see if it load my excel properly.

```
Service
public class ReaderService {

    private List<Person> personDetailsList;

    @Value("${file.path}")
    String filePath;


    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws IOException {

        personDetailsList = new CsvToBeanBuilder<Person>(new FileReader(filePath))
                .withType(Person.class).build().parse();


    }

    public StatisticReport calculateStatistics() {
        Integer firstNameNullCounter = 0;
        Integer lastNameNullCounter = 0;
        Integer ageNullCounter= 0;

       for(Person person : personDetailsList){
           if(person.getFirstName().equals("") || person.getFirstName() == null) {
               firstNameNullCounter++;
           }
           if(person.getLastName().equals("") || person.getLastName() == null) {
               lastNameNullCounter++;
           }
           if(person.getAge() == null){
               ageNullCounter++;
           }
        }

       return new StatisticReport(firstNameNullCounter,lastNameNullCounter,ageNullCounter,calculateAverage());
    }

    public double calculateAverage(){
        return personDetailsList.stream()
                .map(p -> p.getAge() == null ? new Person(p.getFirstName(),p.getLastName(),0) : p)
                .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(Person::getAge));
    }
```

application.properties:

```
file.path=...some path...\data.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make your code more *test-friendly* by using constructor injection

```java
@Service
public class ReaderService {

    private List<Person> personDetailsList;

    public ReaderService(@Value("${file.path}") String csv) throws IOException {
        personDetailsList = new CsvToBeanBuilder<Person>(new FileReader(csv))
                .withType(Person.class).build().parse();
    }
    ...
```

2. Make a Junit test where you can use `ReaderService` as a basic java class (no need for it being a component )

```java
// fast not-spring-aware junit test
class ReaderServiceTest {
  
  @Test
  public void testOne(){
    StatisticReport report = new ReaderService("path_to_file_one").calculateStatistics();
   // actual result testing
  }
  
  @Test
  public void testTwo(){
    StatisticReport report = new ReaderService("path_to_file_two").calculateStatistics();
   // actual result testing
  }
}
```

Comment: there is a way that i can get the path from my application.propperties in my test file?

Comment: didn't you want multiple paths? a path per test?

Comment: 1 same path for all tests, that I already declared in my application.properties

Comment: so you can use it like `value_of_base_path_for_tests + "/file_one.csv"` ?